# Foreign LLC Owner

Tags: united-states, business, arizona

I'm planning to start an LLC in Arizona. I live in Mexico and plan to continue residing there.

The LLC would be created to open a fitness center.

I've tried with LegalZoom, but they just offer LLC creation for American citizens.

Is it possible, as a foreign national, to create an Arizona LLC, be the sole owner, and also work on the business without living in the United States? What kind of special lawyer do I need to help me with this situation?

Comment: Are you able to make this more general (i.e. edit out your specific details) so this question doesn't get closed.  Maybe something along the lines of the first question in the last paragraph?

Comment: [Here are some tips on how to write a general legal question](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/a/303/794).

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what LegalZoom might be providing that limits the applicant to US citizens.

There is one two-page form to fill out.

[Articles of Organization](http://www.azcc.gov/Divisions/Corporations/forms/starpas/formsSTPS/L010-Articles-of-Organization.pdf)

The instructions are clear.

[Instructions L010i Articles of Organization](http://www.azcc.gov/Divisions/Corporations/forms/starpas/instructionsSTPS/L010i-002-Instructions-Articles-of-Organization-STPS.pdf?d=44)

The corporation is required to have a statutory agent in the state. It doesn't matter where the owners live.